# Understanding Fence Code for New Fence

Tags: code-compliance, fence

[image: Image of area new property]

[image: Image of Local fence code]

I'm planning to build a privacy fence around our property. I want it to be as tall as the local code allows. I'm having trouble understanding the code for out lot.

Does the plan above follow code?

Since it is a corner lot does fence on the side near the side road have to be 6 ft?

What layout would be code?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Back and long side maybe good at 8.  The others will need to ask town and get it in writing.  Verbal okays not good enough.

Comment: The DIY site isn't suitable for rendering legal opinions. You can check law.stackexchange.com. Note that without knowing what your _zone_ is, it's not possible to interpret what you've quoted anyway. ...

Comment: ... That said, in general it's clear that the intent behind the regulation is that you need the fence to remain low between the front of the house and a street where there might be driveway access, and on the sides of the house where the side faces another street and the fence is close to the public ROW. I don't think you're going to get away with 8' along the side road, or even on the property line along the main road. You may also have trouble with 8' fencing that isn't strictly _behind_ the front of the house.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say where you are located but based on my experience and looking at your code, I would say you have problems with the fence in your drawing. Your fence exceeds 4 feet where it extends beyond the front of both houses on either side. To be sure, you should show your plan to your local building department (you probably need to do that anyway to obtain a building permit). They are the ones you need to convince.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation, which is not of course authoritative, is that if you want an eight foot fence you need to do it like this.
[image]

The part of your plan outside mine towards the main road must be 4ft.  The part towards the side must be 4 or 6 feet according to its distance from the street.  Who is to really say what a side street side yard is?  But that's my interpretation.

Comment: Also you might consider that while good fences make good neighbors, building an unnecessarily tall fence very close to your neighbor's house, one that puts their windows in shadow for several hours more per day than is necessary, might make bad neighbors.   Very few people can see over a six foot fence without a stool, and if they are making an effort they can see over an eight foot fence too.